# C# TryParseExact returns the same date for everything

Tags: c#, datetime

I have dates that come in in this funky format, I thought I was converting them correctly via this code:

```
String theDate = "2212017";
DateTime date;
DateTime.TryParseExact(theDate.PadLeft(8, '0'), "MMddyyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out date);
MessageBox.Show("TheDate: " + theDate + " output: " + date);
```

Alas it always gives a date of:

`1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM`

For any of my funky dates:

```
5162018
5202020
2212017
1202019
```

Am I just printing it out wrong or is the TryParseExact not working like I think it should.

Comment: Huh, I didn't think there were any months with 51 days in them.

Comment: That format looks like `Mddyyyy`

Comment: Hell it's mmDDyyyy 

Comment: You're never checking if `TryParseExact` parses the date successfully, and you require the format `ddMMyyyy`, but you're passing a date in the format `ddMyyyy`

Comment: Still not testing but I did update the question the format with the padleft should be MMddyyyy , still same results though ?

Comment: [Are you sure](http://rextester.com/VUSZE62951)?

Comment: ahhhh had to refresh project for some reason now all is good!

Answer (score 2):

Parse exact needs the right number of digits, and your days value is missing leading zeros. Pad it out.

Try

```
DateTime.TryParseExact
(
    theDate.PadLeft(8,'0'), 
    "ddMMyyyy", 
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, 
    out date
);
```

Comment: I don't think those 20's are the month